# Portal in EEVEE using Holdout in Blender 2.93

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I'm trying to test out an idea of a camera traveling through a doorway/portal leading to an alternate world. I've made a doorway with a holdout texture to be used to see through to the next destination. I know there was some Holdout features have been made possible in Eevee as of Blender 2.9x, but is this method of using Holdout still only possible in Cycles?

- Scene A[image: Scene A]
- Scene B[image: Scene B]

This is what I've tried to do in the Compositing section in order to get that masking effect...
[image: Compositing Nodes]

However, when it renders, the holdout texture is not alpha'd away. Perhaps the best method is to render both scenes independently, then take it into Blender's video editing and alpha-over the holdout there? Or is there actually a way to do this within the rendering process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty...solution is much simpler than I thought.

*Output Properties > Output > Color > RGBA*

I simply did not have the output color settings to include alpha channels!

So in that case, holdout does indeed work in Eevee!!

[image]

Comment: I like the portal thing. It's cool.